# Python Selenium clicking next button until the end

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

This is a follow up question from my first [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237290/web-scraping-with-selenium/36237414), and I am trying to scrape a website and have Selenium click on `next` (until it cant be clicked) and collect the results as well.

This is the html tag from the website with the button:

```
<div class="pager results-display">
  <span class="action-btn prev inactive" data-page="1">Prev</span>
  <span class="action-btn inactive" data-page="1">1</span>  # Currently in page 1 thus inactive
  <span class="action-btn" data-page="2">2</span>
  <span class="action-btn" data-page="3">3</span> 
  <span class="action-btn" data-page="4">4</span>
  <span class="action-btn" data-page="5">5</span>
  <span class="action-btn" data-page="6">6</span>
  <span class="action-btn" data-page="7">7</span>
  <span class="action-btn" data-page="8">8</span> 
  <span class="action-btn" data-page="9">9</span>
  <span class="action-btn" data-page="10">10</span>
  <span class="action-btn" data-page="11">11</span> 
  <span class="action-btn" data-page="12">12</span>
  <span class="action-btn" data-page="13">13</span>
  <span class="action-btn" data-page="14">14</span>
  <span class="action-btn next" data-page="2">Next</span>
</div>
<div class="no-results-display hidden" style="display: none;">
                    No companies matched your search. Try again.
                </div>
```

I've tried this code:

```
elm = driver.find_element_by_name('pager results-display')
elm.click()
```

And I've also checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838164/how-can-i-make-selenium-click-on-the-next-button-until-it-is-no-longer-possibl) out, but still wasn't able to solve it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`pager results-display` are actually two classes that belongs to the button's parent element. They aren't name attribute, and `find_element_by_name` gets only one name anyway. Try

```
elm = driver.find_element_by_class_name('next')
elm.click()
```

Notice that you might have to relocate the button each time if the DOM has changed after the click.

To click in loop as long as the button is active you can check if the buuton has class `inactive`

```
while True:
    elm = driver.find_element_by_class_name('next')
    if 'inactive' in elm.get_attribute('class'):
        break;
    elm.click()
```

Comment: Hello, this works. But how can I structure this into a loop that clicks on next until it ends? From what I observed, when the page is at the last page, `next` is still there, but the `html code` changes to `<span class="action-btn next inactive" data-page="14">Next</span>`

Comment: @jakewong I added example in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. This gives me what I'm looking for :)